# error in visual c++ code about namespace

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I am just a beginner in C++. I have errors with namespaces in Visual C++. Here is the code which include files I have to add for this foundation. The error says the name must be a namespace name. I add whole code is source folder. There is not single file in header. Wow many files do I have to add?

```
using namespace System;
int main() 
{
    if (Environment::HasShutdownStarted)
        Console::WriteLine("Shutting down.");
    else
        Console::WriteLine("Not shutting down.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf72fa24-cd1d-46d1-aa1b-f0906b01a532/what-includefile-is-necessary-for-using-namespace-system?forum=vcgeneral) you could find the answer.

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand your question for me, but if the code you posted is really everything, then you are clearly missing some includes. You will need at least the headers that define `System:Console` and `System::Environment`. If it is *not* the complete code, then please [read about SSCCEs](http:sscce.org) and improve your question.

Comment: thanku sir done it..and pardon as i dont knw english..have a nice day..lots of love

Answer (score 0):

You should add this:

`#using <mscorlib.dll>`

If you want to use System namespace. Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
```

It is used to let the compiler know you are working with the system.